# Css text spills out of div

Tags: css, text, html

I really dont know what to do.

I made a really simple guestbook, its ok and all, but when showing the comments

the text spills out from the div

I was trying with pre but didnt work

here is the css

```
.guestbook_content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #FFE4E1;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#box {
    width: 628px;
    height: 438px;
    background: #fefefd ;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
```

the html and php

```
<div id='box'>
                        <div id='box_title'></div>
                        <div id="box_text">
                            <?php 
                            if(isset($_POST['mehet'])) {
                                $message= '';
                                $the_name= mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['nev']));
                                $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['comment']));
                                $date = date('Y.m.d H:i:s');

                                if(!empty($comment) && !empty($the_name)) {
                                //mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendeg (name, comment, date) VALUES ('$the_name', $comment', '$date')") or die(mysql_error());
                                mysql_query(" INSERT INTO guesstb(the_name, comment, date) VALUES ('$the_name', '$comment', '$date') ");
                                }else {
                                    $message= '<b><font color="darkred">Pleasse fill out all inputs</b></font>';
                                }   
                            }
                            ?>
                            <?php echo $message; ?>
                            <form action='<?php echo the_permalink();?>' method='POST'>


                            <label for='nev' class='gbl'>Name:</label>
                            <input type='text' name='the_name' id='the_name' class='gbi'>

                            <label for='comm' class='gbl'>Comment:</label>
                            <textarea name='comment' id='comm' rows='5' cols='60' class='gbt'></textarea>
                            <input type='submit' class='submit' value='Beküld' name='mehet'>
                            </form> 
                            <?php 
                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guesstbORDER BY date DESC");
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {

                            ?><div class='guestbook_head'><span>sent by:</span> <b><?php echo $row['nev']; ?></b> <span> - date:</span> <?php echo $row['date']; ?> </div><?

                                ?>

                                    <div class='guestbook_content'><?echo $row['comment'];?></div>

                                <?

                            }

                    ?>
```

could please someone could give me hint

Comment: is it possible for you to post some generated html code for testing instead of the php one? That would make it easy for me to test.

Answer (score 1):

```
.guestbook_content {
    width: 100%; <-- drop this rule
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

#box {
    width: 628px;
}
```

You gave child div width: 100% + padding 5px, which makes = 100% of parent div :628px + 5px left padding + 5px right padding so child div is 638px wide. Just drop 100% width on child. All you need is padding.

Here is jsfiddle with your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/crg2U/2/
And here is with droped 100% width on child : http://jsfiddle.net/crg2U/3/